# Changing the value of stdout in a C++ program

Tags: c++, c, stdout, filehandle

I have a Windows C++ program that is doing something like:

```
  FILE* pf = ...;
  *stdout = *pf;    // stdout is defined in stdio.h
```

I'm looking for an explanation about what happens when you change the value of the stdout file handle. Is this just a way of redirecting stdout?

-cr

Comment: I've thought about doing this in the past, and never have because I've not found a good answer either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change `stdout` by assignment instead of by using the tool designated (in C, `freopen()` as Adam Rosenfield said - and by extension, in C++), then you leave yourself open to all sorts of liabilities.

- It is not clear that `cout` will also be redirected.
- You will likely leak a file descriptor (which may not matter).
- You might not flush the original stdout properly - losing information.
- You might leak memory associated with the original file pointer (which again may not matter).
- If anything closes `pf`, then you are liable for double-free errors (crashes).

It is far better to do the job cleanly.

(Demo code isn't necessarily written by, or even scrutinized by, the most experienced people in a vendor's coding team.  If it looks dubious, that may be because it is dubious.)

Comment: And most importantly, you invoke **undefined behavior**. The C standard is very clear on the fact that using a copy of a `FILE` in place of the original invokes UB, and I believe the C++ standard will agree with C on this.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, when you change stdout, you're effectively redirecting it elsewhere.  However, you should **not** directly assign to stdout like that.  If you want to redirect stdout, you should instead use [`freopen()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/freopen.html).

You should never directly manipulate FILE objects - you should treat them as opaque types, and only interact with them via the functions in the `<stdio>` library.  Jonathan lists some good reasons why.

From the C99 standard, section 7.19.3, paragraph 6:

> The address of the FILE object used to control a stream may be significant; a copy of a
>   FILE object need not serve in place of the original.

Comment: I didn't write this code. It's in some sample code from a toolkit vendor.